# javascript: using reduce to collectively add for some fields?

Tags: javascript

if I have the given array:

```js
let arr = [['james', 49],['scott', 19], ['james', 51]];

arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  acc[curr[0]] = curr[0];
  acc[curr[0]].push({
    price: curr[1]
  }) 
  return acc;
},{})
```

the result is:

```
{ 
   james: [{price: 51}].
   scott: [{price: 19},
}
```

the last value for `james` is `51` so it's overriding the `49`.  Is there anyway I can combine the values if they keys are the same so that it would show `100`?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your code, it throws "acc[curr[0]].push is not a function" exception. Make sure you posted the exact code you run

Answer (score 1):

You could store an object with price zero and add the proce of the same group.

```js
let array = [['james', 49], ['scott', 19], ['james', 51]],
    result = array.reduce((acc, [name, price]) => {
        acc[name] ??= [{ price: 0 }];
        acc[name][0].price += price;
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks @Nina ...what is the `??=` operator..I've never seen that used before.

Comment: it is the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object to assign a sum to each name. For example:

```js
let arr = [['james', 49],['scott', 19], ['james', 51]];
let sums = {};
arr.forEach(x => sums[x[0]] = (sums[x[0]] >= 0 ? sums[x[0]] + x[1] : x[1]));
console.log(sums);
```